# How do I read a floating point value and print the closest numbers less than or greater than that value?

Tags: java

I am having trouble writing a program that reads a floating point value (double) and prints the closest whole numbers less than and greater than that value. For example, if the number is 28.466, the program would print 28 and 29. I want to use Joptionpane to receive the input from the user

Comment: What have you written until now? What is failing in what you wrote?

Comment: There should be something in the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) package that will help you.  Then again, I don't know whether that's your issue--you're not clear on what your trouble is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.floor(x)` and `Math.ceil(x)` to get the floor and ceiling of a double `x`.